# NoSuchMethodError while using JExcel API

Tags: java, excel, servlets, jxl, nosuchmethoderror

I keep getting the following error while writing to an excel file using JExcel API.
Any ideas ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jxl.biff.XFRecord$XFType.<init>(Ljxl/biff/XFRecord$1;)V
    at jxl.biff.XFRecord.<clinit>(XFRecord.java:346)
    at jxl.write.WritableWorkbook.<clinit>(WritableWorkbook.java:57)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:411)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:393)
    at controleur.ExportController.exporterFormation(ExportController.java:194)
    at controleur.ExportController.doPost(ExportController.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    ... 53 more
```

Thanks a lot !

---

Well I switched to Apache POI and it worked perfectly, thanks for the answers though !

Comment: Which version of JExcel do you use?

Comment: The last one I think, 2.6.12

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error usually happens when you have not the same version of the library at runtime as the one used at compile time. Verify which version of JExcel is deployed in your web server.